# Identify duplicate islands in a matrix and change their values

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix:

```
m <- matrix(c(
  1,    1,    1,    0,    0,    0,
  0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
  3,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
  3,    0,    0,    0,    0,    2,
  3,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
  3,    0,    0,    0,    2,    2),
  ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    3    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    3    0    0    0    0    2 # <- island 3, value 2
[5,]    3    0    0    0    0    0
[6,]    3    0    0    0    2    2 # <- island  4, also value 2
```

In this matrix, there are four 'islands', i.e. non-zero values separated by zeros:

(1) an island composed of three 1's, (2) four 3's, (3) one 2, and (4) two 2's.

Thus, two islands are composed of the value `2`. I want to identify such 'duplicate' islands and change the values of one of the 'islands' (either will do) to the next available number (`4` in this case):

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    3    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    3    0    0    0    0    2
[5,]    3    0    0    0    0    0
[6,]    3    0    0    0    4    4
```

Comment: Not clear (I see 3 'islands', -- why is the next value 4?, ...). Please explain it more and give an expected output as well. Also make sure your examples are [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: There are 4 islands: one made up of 1's, one made up of 3's and 2 made up of 2's. 4 is a number that hasn't already been taken and is one more than the maximum number already used.

Comment: As I said in the original question, change either of the islands labelled '2' to '4' but not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fun question! Let's take a more involved case

```
(M <- matrix(c(1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 
               0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2), 6, 6))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    1    1    0    0    1
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    3    0    3    3    0    0
# [4,]    3    0    0    0    0    2
# [5,]    3    0    2    0    0    0
# [6,]    3    0    0    0    2    2
```

Here's a graph-based solution.

```
library(igraph)
# Indices of nonzero matrix elements
idx <- which(M != 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
# Adjacency matrix for matrix entries
# Two entries are adjacent if their column or row number differs by one
# Also, due to idx, an implicit condition is also that the two entries are the same
adj <- 1 * (as.matrix(dist(idx, method = "manhattan")) == 1)
# Creating loops as to take into account singleton islands
diag(adj) <- 1
# A corresponding graphs
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adj, mode = "undirected")
# Connected components of this graph
cmps <- clusters(g)
# Going over unique values of M
for(i in 1:max(M)) {
  # Islands of value i
  un <- unique(cmps$membership[M[idx] == i])
  # More than one island?
  if(length(un) > 1)
    # If so, let's go over islands 2, 3, ...
    for(cmp in un[-1])
      # ... and replace corresponding matrix entries by max(M) + 1
      M[idx[cmps$membership == cmp, , drop = FALSE]] <- max(M) + 1
}

M
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    1    1    0    0    4
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    3    0    7    7    0    0
# [4,]    3    0    0    0    0    6
# [5,]    3    0    2    0    0    0
# [6,]    3    0    0    0    5    5
```

Also note that using `adj` alone we could find all the islands if we could find its permutation leading to a block-diagonal matrix with the maximal number of blocks. Then each block would correspond to an island. However, I couldn't find an R implementation of a relevant procedure.

Comment: I was trying to use a depth first search, this is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

'Islands' of non-zero values can be identified by `raster::clump`*. Then use `data.table` convenience functions to identify which values should be updated.

```
library(raster)
library(data.table)

# get index of non-zero values. re-order to match the clump order
ix <- which(m != 0, arr.ind = TRUE)
ix <- ix[order(ix[ , "row"]), ]

# get clumps
cl <- clump(raster(m))
cl_ix <- cl@data@values

# put stuff in a data.table and order by x
d <- data.table(ix, x = m[ix], cl_ix = cl_ix[!is.na(cl_ix)])
setorder(d, x, cl_ix)

# for each x, create a counter of runs of clump index
d[ , g := rleid(cl_ix), by = x]

# for 'duplicated' runs...
# ...add to x based on runs of x and clump index runs
d[g > 1, x := max(d$x) + rleid(x, g)]

# update matrix
m2 <- m
m2[as.matrix(d[ , .(row, col)])] <- d$x

m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    1    1    0    0    1
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    3    0    3    3    0    0
# [4,]    3    0    0    0    0    2
# [5,]    3    0    2    0    0    0
# [6,]    3    0    0    0    2    2

m2
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    1    1    0    0    4
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    3    0    7    7    0    0
# [4,]    3    0    0    0    0    2
# [5,]    3    0    5    0    0    0
# [6,]    3    0    0    0    6    6
```

---

*Note that the `clump` function requires that the `igraph` package is available.

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be achieved with package `TraMineR`.

```
islander <- function(mat) {
  require(TraMineR)
  rows.mat.seq <- seqdef(mat)  # seeks all sequences in rows 
  cols.mat.seq <- seqdef(t(mat))  # tranposed version
  rows <- seqpm(rows.mat.seq, 22)$MIndex  # seeks for sub sequence 2-2 in rows
  cols <- seqpm(cols.mat.seq, 22)$MIndex  # seeks for sub sequence 2-2 in columns
  if (length(cols) == 0) {  # the row case
    mat[rows, which(mat[rows, ] == 2)] <- 4
    return(mat)
  } else {  # the column case
    mat[which(mat[, cols] == 2), cols] <- 4
    return(mat)
  }
}
```

***Yielding***

```
> islander(row.mat)
...
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    3    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    3    0    0    0    0    2
[5,]    3    0    0    0    0    0
[6,]    3    0    0    0    4    4

> islander(col.mat)
...
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    3    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    3    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    3    0    0    0    0    4
[6,]    3    0    0    2    0    4
```

*Note:* If your island is longer, you need to adept the code, e.g. for length of island is 3 do `seqpm(., 222)`. It is certainly possible to implement the consideration of all cases into the function.

***Data***

```
row.mat <- structure(c(1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2), .Dim = c(6L, 
                                                                                      6L))
col.mat <- structure(c(1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2), .Dim = c(6L, 
                                                                                       6L))

> row.mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    3    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    3    0    0    0    0    2
[5,]    3    0    0    0    0    0
[6,]    3    0    0    0    2    2
> col.mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    3    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    3    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    3    0    0    0    0    2
[6,]    3    0    0    2    0    2
```

Answer (score 0):

It was harder than I thought becase of the "not both" condition, I achieved the result with a `while` loop for now, we'll se if it can be improved:

(basically we move by row and check if the island is found, if so we end our research)

```
# some useful variables
i=1 # row counter
counter=0 # check if island is found
max_m <- max(m) #finds the max value in the matrix, to fill

while(counter == 0) {

  if (any(m[i, ] == 2)) { # check if we find the island in the row, otherwise skip
    row <- m[i, ]
    row[row == 2] <- max_m + 1 # here we change the value
    m[i, ] <- row
    counter <- counter + 1
  }

  i = i + 1 # we move up one row
  #cat("row number: ", i, "\n") # sanity check to see if it was an infinite loop
}
m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    3    0    0    0    0    0
# [4,]    3    0    0    0    0    4
# [5,]    3    0    0    0    0    0
# [6,]    3    0    0    0    2    2
```

This is far from perfect, because we move by rows, so if the first island is across a column we would change only the first value.

Example of unexpected result:

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    3    0    0    0    0    0
# [4,]    3    0    0    0    0    4
# [5,]    3    0    0    0    0    2 # problem here
# [6,]    3    0    0    0    0    0
```

Data used:

```
m <- matrix(c(rep(1, 3),
              rep(0, 9),
              3, 
              rep(0, 5),
              3,
              rep(0, 4),
              2,
              3,
              rep(0, 5),
              3,
              rep(0,3),
              rep(2, 2)),ncol=6,nrow=6, byrow = T)
```